# How to change all folders and files permessions base on folder name?

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

For exemple we have  folders named with permission numbers 555 or 700 or 777... how can we take the file name and change all the subfolders and files with permissions based on the folder name ?
so if we apply it on the folder 555 the current folder and everything inside will have permission as 555
i've tried

```
find . -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -type d | xargs chmod -Rv [0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

but it only takes the first folder name and apply it on everything it i want it to treat each folder name ( named withe permission) seperately
thank you.

Comment: `find  ./ -type d -perm 555 -exec chmod -R 555 {} \;`  --> That would find all **directories** with the permission 555 and change all files INSIDE said directories to 555.

Comment: +x (for example) on directory doesn't mean the same thing on a file

Comment: thank you for ur answer but what if i had 1000 floder and i can't go through all of them but still thank you for your time i learned something new

Answer (score 0):

> i've tried find . -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -type d | xargs chmod -Rv [0-9][0-9][0-9] but it only takes the first folder name and apply it on everything it i want it to treat each folder name ( named withe permission) seperately

Your attempt is wrong in several ways, among them:

1. The `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` pattern matches names that include characters that are not octal digits.
2. The `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` pattern will be expanded by the shell when it parses the command.  If the expansion is successful, then the first matching name will give the mode to apply.  If the expansion is *not* successful then (by default) the pattern itself will be passed through to `chmod`, which will reject it as an invalid mode.
3. By default, the `xargs` command will take as many inputs as it can to form arguments to *one* command.  So in your example command, if `find` identifies folders `700`, `555`, `755`, and `400` then the `xargs` will end up executing something like this:

   ```
   chmod -Rv <... expansion of [0-9][0-9][0-9] ...> 700 555 755 400
   ```

   Even in the event that the pattern expanded to nothing (which could happen under slightly different circumstances) you have a result similar to before: the first directory name would provide the mode, and all the others would be updated to that mode.

This variation should do what you want:

```
find . -name "[0-7][0-7][0-7]" -type d |
  sed 's,^.*/\([^/]*\)$,\1\n\0,' |
  xargs -r -l2 chmod -Rv
```

The `sed` command takes each path emitted by `find`, extracts the base name, and puts that on a separate, preceding line.  For example, if one of the lines `find` emits is

```
./subdir/755
```

then sed will change that to

```
755
./subdir/755
```

.  That is, the mode to apply and the directory to which to apply it.

Then the `-l2` option to `xargs` tells it to use (at most) two input lines in forming each `chmod` command, so you will end up with a series of commands of the form

```
chmod -Rv 755 ./subdir/755
```

The `-r` option to `xargs` is a nicety that tells it to avoid executing any commands at all if no lines are read from the standard input.

#### Addendum: the `sed` expression in more detail

[Note: I have slightly simplified the `sed` command given in the original version of this answer.]

The `sed` command ...

```
  sed 's,^.*/\([^/]*\)$,\1\n\0,'
```

... processes each input line according to the given expression, a `s`ubstitute command with comma (`,`) delimters.

- The target pattern is `^\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)$`.  This matches

  - a sequence starting at the beginning of the line (`^`),
  - matching any number of any character `.*`,
  - followed by a slash (`/`) character,
  - followed by any number of any character other than slash (`[^/]*`)
  - running to the end of the line (`$`).
- The part after the last slash is captured as a group.
- the replacement text is

  - the contents of the first (only) capture group (`\1`), followed by
  - a newline (`\n`), followed by
  - the whole match (`\0`), which will be the original line because the match is anchored to both the beginning and end of the line.

`sed` will match each input line against the target pattern.  Any line containing at least one slash will match, and every line emitted by the given `find` command will satisfy that criterion.  The whole match (which will be the whole line) will be replaced by the given replacement, consisting of two lines -- one containing the tail of the original line following the last slash, and the other containing the whole original line.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, would u please explain more this part of the command sed  's,^\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)$,\2\n\1\2,' i get what it does but i dont frankly understand the syntax meaning . thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Not sure understand the question.

Need sample input and sample output to understand.

#### Suggesting following solution:

```
 dir_name="555"; chmod -R "$dir_name" $(find . -path "*$dir_name*")
```

#### Explanation

`dir_name="555";`        : Assign a variable `dir_name` that holds the directory name  `555` and the `chmod`  permission value `555`

`$(find . -path "*$dir_name*")`: List all files under current directory having `555` somewhere in their path.

`chmod -R "$dir_name"`       : Chmod command using the value of `dir_name` `555`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this.

```sh
find . -type d -name '???' -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I'{}' chmod -R  '{}' '{}'
```

- `-type d` -- find only directories.
- `-name ???` -- this will cover directories named 555, 700, 777, etc
- `printf '%f\n'` -- print only directory's name.

To be really safe, I would add another option (`-maxdepth`):

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '???' -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I'{}' chmod -R  '{}' '{}'
```

- `maxdepth 1` -- Don't do any search on subfolders.

Comment: thank you for your answer it's working I really appreciate it, can u explain the usage of  '{}' and when you apply them most of the time i really struggle with that

Comment: `{}` is to save & replace. The first one is for saving the output of `find`, the second and the last will be replaced by this save.